# How to detect if a string is already utf8-encoded?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, mojibake

I have some strings like this:

```
u'ThaÃÂ¯lande'
```

This was "Thaïlande" and I dont know how it's been encoded, but I need to bring it back to "Thaïlande", then URL-encode it.

Is there a way to guess if a string has already been encoded with Python 2?

Comment: Your sample is *incomplete*. Please provide the `repr()` output of an actual faulty string. You are missing some non-printable bytes there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have what is called a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). You could use statistical analysis to see if there is a unusual number of Latin-1 characters in there in a combination typical of UTF-8 bytes, or if there are any CP1252-specific characters in there.

There already is a package that does this for you *and* repairs the damage if a Mojibake is detected: [`ftfy`](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> The goal of ftfy is to take in bad Unicode and output good Unicode, for use in your Unicode-aware code.

and

> The ftfy.fix_encoding() function will look for evidence of mojibake and, when possible, it will undo the process that produced it to get back the text that was supposed to be there.
>
> Does this sound impossible? It’s really not. UTF-8 is a well-designed encoding that makes it obvious when it’s being misused, and a string of mojibake usually contains all the information we need to recover the original string.

Comment: I've pointed my problem: if you look at the **source code** of urllib `def unquote(s):` you'll see that `append(unquote(str(bits[i])).decode('latin1'))` which is 'latin1' whereas my code is utf-8. I dont know why I'm the only one to have that problem but I'll have to re-write my own GET parameters handling... it seems that the `unquote()` is buggy. I see this https://bugs.python.org/issue8136

Comment: @OlivierPons: that only applies if you passed in a *unicode string*. Don't pass in a Unicode string if you have UTF-8 bytes in it.

Comment: @OlivierPons: although I do agree that the `urllib.unquote()` and `urlparse.unquote()` functions are essentially broken in that behaviour, the work-around is to ensure you pass in ASCII bytes:  `unquote(unicodestr.encode('ascii')).decode('utf8')`, where I assume the entry has been properly URL-encoded (meaning it is ASCII safe too).

Comment: You made my day! I had to copy paste `parse_qsl` which is buggy (and part of the python27 core) because it does `unquote(nv[1].replace('+', ' '))` whereas it should do - correct me if I'm wrong - `unquote(nv[1].encode('ascii').replace('+', ' '))`

Comment: You'd pass in the URL already encoded to ASCII to `parse_qsl()`.

Comment: I've tried this but only some values are not ascii... and this breaks the whole string decoding.. Thank you you've put me on the right track!